# Admob not appearing on beta apk android

Tags: android, admob

I have an Android app which is published in in beta mode on play store. I have code integrated in the app to display admobs. Code works fine on simulator if I add test device id.

When I download beta version of my app from play store, admob doesn't show up. Even during development, it doesn't appear on real device.

Is it like admob only appears in production?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is just likely that there are no ads available for app right now.
Look at the logcat, it will tell you what is happening.